# When generating new views they are stacking on top of each other

Tags: android, layout, view, android-framelayout, layoutparams

When I click my button for adding new buttons to a framelayout, the new buttons are stacking on top of each other.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Button newAlarm = new Button(Hop_Timer.this);
                newAlarm.setText(alarmMinutes.getText() + " Addition - Remove");
                newAlarm.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                FrameLayout alarmsFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.display_alarms);
                alarmsFrame.addView(newAlarm);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you use a `FrameLayout` view. Try `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and everything will be fine.